# Como pegar dados de bootstrap modal e enviar para o PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Estou precisando pegar os dados do formulário do Modal via Ajax
Meu código:

```
var url = 'fotovisita.php';
var data = $('#foto').serialize();
var type = "POST";

$(document).on('click', '#save-foto', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/json',

        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#save-foto').val("Saving");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#foto')[0].reset();
            $('#cadastraFoto').modal('hide');
            console.log(data)
            //$('#call sucess message').html(data); 
        }
    });
});
```

Meu Modal

```
<div class="container">
<!-- MODAL FOTO -->

<div id="cadastraFoto" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="cadastraFotoLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title text-xs-center" id="cadastraFotoLabel">Cadastro de Fotos Visitas</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"> <!-- FORM -->
                <form name="foto" id="foto" data-async data-target="#rating-modal" method="POST" action="/sistema/instancias/agendavisita/fotovisita.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="">
                    <div class="row justify-content-md-left">
                        <div class="col col-lg-3">
                            <label class="control-label" for="datavisita">Data Vísita</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-lg-6">    
                            <input type="date" name="datavisita" class="form-control  form-control-sm form-group small" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row justify-content-md-left">
                        <div class="col col-lg-3">
                            <label class="control-label" for="idvisita">Visíta</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col col-md-6'>    
                            <select>
                                <option value="1">Arquiteto</option>
                                <option value="2">Engenheiroo</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row justify-content-md-left">
                        <div class="col col-lg-3">
                            <label class="control-label" for="percentandamento">Porcentagem Andamento</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-md-6 slidecontainer">
                            <input type="range" name="percentandamento" id="range_weight" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="form-control-range slider" oninput="range_weight_disp.value = range_weight.value">
                            <output  id="range_weight_disp"></output>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-md-left">
                        <div class="col col-lg-3">
                            <label class="control-label" for="caminhofoto">Foto</label>
                        </div>
                        <div>   
                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file form-control-sm form-group small" name='caminhofoto' id="caminhofoto" multiple="multiple" />
                            <span id="hidden_img_show"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-md-left">
                        <div class="col col-lg-3">
                            <label class="control-label" class="control-label" for="descricaofoto">Descrição Foto</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-md-auto'>                
                            <textarea name="descricaofoto" cols="25" rows="3" class="form-control  form-control-sm form-group small" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div>

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                            <button type="button"  name="save-foto" id="save-foto" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <span class="fas fa-plus"></span>
                                Salvar</button> 
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<!-- fim modal foto -->
```

Meu objetivo é pegar todos campos digitados e enviar para a pagina PHP
editacli.php que nele tem já os métodos para receber os $_POST['']; de cada elemento do formulário e fazer o tratamento salvando no banco e depois quero fechar o Modal e exibir uma mensagem na tela de Modal, "Dados salvos com sucesso".

Porém não está funcionado esse código Ajax, quando clico no botão na pagina que recebe os dados via $_POST, não está retornando os dados do formulário.

OBS: Já testei minha pagina de insert do PHP sem o modal e ela está salvando normal, só não estou sabendo como resolver com o Modal.

Comment: Teu modal é HTML ou foi gerado via Jquery ? Pode dar mais informações ?

Comment: é HTML. 
Inclui o modal na pergunta agora.

Comment: Deixa eu te pergunta uma segunda coisa o problema é no .ajax({}) do seu Jquery ?

Comment: Fiz um edição no ajax e ficou como na pergunta atualizada.
No caso ele na aba rede do navegador chama normal o arquivo `fotovisita.php` e dentro dele eu coloquei `echo $_POST['datavisita'];` para ver se retornava o valor digitado no modal, e da erro de variável não definida.
Creio que seja algum erro no Ajax.

Comment: Abre o Log do teu navegador , caso você não saiba: aperta com o direito do mouse na sua página vai aparecer "inspecionar" dai você vai na aba console, se tiver algo em vermelho lá tem um erro.
Aproveita faz o seguinte troca teu Jquery muda para esse CDN "jquery-3.3.1.min.js" se o erro for no teu $.Ajax({}) pode ser apenas a versão do teu Jquery.

Comment: Erro do console só tem esse:
GET https://eluxer.net/code?sck=1&id=105&subid=51763_4926_ 404 (Not Found)

Meu JQuery: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82879/discussion-between-ricardo-lucas-and-jb).